# symfony2 no routes working

Tags: php, symfony, lamp, ubuntu

LAST UPDATE:

This changed messed drupal too so I reinstalled xampp, I don't have this problem atm and I think the subject is closed.

UPDATE:

weird I dealt with the errors shown on the pages. I got rid of the line : : throw 0 < count($allow) ? new MethodNotAllowedException(array_unique($allow)) : new ResourceNotFoundException(); [1/2] ResourceNotFoundException:

and it seems to work

but when I deleted line 2117 in classes.php (the elseif so 3 lines

```
  elseif (is_object($controller)) {
  $repr = get_class($controller);
  }
```

) 
in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Symfony/app/cache/dev/classes.php I get a new error even when I put the elseif back ...

Here's the message:

hoops, looks like something went wrong. 1/1 FatalErrorException in classes.php line 2117: Parse Error: syntax error, unexpected 'elseif' (T_ELSEIF)

in classes.php line 2117

---

I'm starting TOMORROW a job on Symfony2 for my first professional experience on that but strangely this time I have problems making it work on my lamp/Kubuntu .

Here's what I try:

downloaded the : Symfony_Standard_Vendors_2.6.4.zip (so it's in the zip file) that is the kunbutu download folder
mv Symfony ../../../var/www

these urls do not work:

http://localhost/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/hello/winzou
http://localhost/Symfony/web/app_dev.php/hello/World

the error for both pages (apart the obvious part of Get/hello/..) shown is :
 ERROR - Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No route found for "GET /hello/winzou"" at /opt/lampp/htdocs/Symfony/app/cache/dev/classes.php line 2017

```
in app/cache/dev/classes.php at line 2017  -

if ($referer = $request->headers->get('referer')) {
$message .= sprintf(' (from "%s")', $referer);
}
throw new NotFoundHttpException($message, $e);
} catch (MethodNotAllowedException $e) {
$message = sprintf('No route found for "%s %s": Method Not Allowed (Allow: %s)', $request->getMethod(), $request->getPathInfo(), implode(', ', $e->getAllowedMethods()));
throw new MethodNotAllowedHttpException($e->getAllowedMethods(), $message, $e);

at RouterListener ->onKernelRequest (object(GetResponseEvent), 'kernel.request', object(TraceableEventDispatcher))
at call_user_func (array(object(RouterListener), 'onKernelRequest'), object(GetResponseEvent), 'kernel.request', object(TraceableEventDispatcher))
in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/Debug/WrappedListener.php at line 61  +
at WrappedListener ->__invoke (object(GetResponseEvent), 'kernel.request', object(ContainerAwareEventDispatcher))
at call_user_func (object(WrappedListener), object(GetResponseEvent), 'kernel.request', object(ContainerAwareEventDispatcher))
in app/cache/dev/classes.php at line 1790  +
at EventDispatcher ->doDispatch (array(object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener), object(WrappedListener)), 'kernel.request', object(GetResponseEvent))
in app/cache/dev/classes.php at line 1723  +
at EventDispatcher ->dispatch ('kernel.request', object(GetResponseEvent))
in app/cache/dev/classes.php at line 1884  +
at ContainerAwareEventDispatcher ->dispatch ('kernel.request', object(GetResponseEvent))
in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/EventDispatcher/Debug/TraceableEventDispatcher.php at line 112  +
at TraceableEventDispatcher ->dispatch ('kernel.request', object(GetResponseEvent))
in app/bootstrap.php.cache at line 3011  +
at HttpKernel ->handleRaw (object(Request), '1')
in app/bootstrap.php.cache at line 2984  +
at HttpKernel ->handle (object(Request), '1', true)
in app/bootstrap.php.cache at line 3133  +
at ContainerAwareHttpKernel ->handle (object(Request), '1', true)
in app/bootstrap.php.cache at line 2377  +
at Kernel ->handle (object(Request))
in web/app_dev.php at line 28  +
```

and :

[2/2] NotFoundHttpException: No route found for "GET /hello/World"  +

```
if ($referer = $request->headers->get('referer')) {
$message .= sprintf(' (from "%s")', $referer);
}
throw new NotFoundHttpException($message, $e);
} catch (MethodNotAllowedException $e) {
$message = sprintf('No route found for "%s %s": Method Not Allowed (Allow: %s)', $request->getMethod(), $request->getPathInfo(), implode(', ', $e->getAllowedMethods()));
throw new MethodNotAllowedHttpException($e->getAllowedMethods(), $message, $e);


if ($referer = $request->headers->get('referer')) {
$message .= sprintf(' (from "%s")', $referer);
}
throw new NotFoundHttpException($message, $e);
} catch (MethodNotAllowedException $e) {
$message = sprintf('No route found for "%s %s": Method Not Allowed (Allow: %s)', $request->getMethod(), $request->getPathInfo(), implode(', ', $e->getAllowedMethods()));
throw new MethodNotAllowedHttpException($e->getAllowedMethods(), $message, $e);
```

[1/2] ResourceNotFoundException:   -

```
in app/cache/dev/appDevUrlMatcher.php at line 244  -
            }
            throw 0 < count($allow) ? new MethodNotAllowedException(array_unique($allow)) : new ResourceNotFoundException();
        }
    }
```

and it's not pretty but here's what the whole page shows:

---

Symfony
Search on Symfony website
Exception detected!
No route found for "GET /hello/World"
404 Not Found - NotFoundHttpException
1 linked Exception:

```
ResourceNotFoundException »
```

[2/2] NotFoundHttpException: No route found for "GET /hello/World"  +
[1/2] ResourceNotFoundException:   +
Logs  -
1 error

```
ERROR - Uncaught PHP Exception Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException: "No route found for "GET /hello/World"" at /opt/lampp/htdocs/Symfony/app/cache/dev/classes.php line 2017
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\WrappedListener::__invoke".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\WrappedListener::__invoke".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\WrappedListener::__invoke".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\WrappedListener::__invoke".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\WrappedListener::__invoke".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\WrappedListener::__invoke".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\WrappedListener::__invoke".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\WrappedListener::__invoke".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\WrappedListener::__invoke".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.request" to listener "Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\Debug\WrappedListener::__invoke".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\DataCollector\RouterDataCollector::onKernelController".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Acme\DemoBundle\EventListener\ControllerListener::onKernelController".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DataCollector\RequestDataCollector::onKernelController".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ControllerListener::onKernelController".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\ParamConverterListener::onKernelController".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\HttpCacheListener::onKernelController".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\SecurityListener::onKernelController".
DEBUG - Notified event "kernel.controller" to listener "Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\EventListener\TemplateListener::onKernelController".
```

Stack Trace (Plain Text)  +

---

So my guess is to to change the line 2017 of classes.php but what to put ?

I also try in the folder Symfony as suggested by a tutorial:

chmod 777 -R app/cache
chmod 777 -R app/logs

Still same problem ...

---

The app/config/routes is indeed empty, there's no routes folder what should I put? and how do I see the difference between dev and prod?

Try set 2 and 3 and got this in step 3 :

[router] Current routes
  Name                      Method Scheme Host Path
  _wdt                      ANY    ANY    ANY  /_wdt/{token}
  _profiler_home            ANY    ANY    ANY  /_profiler/
  _profiler_search          ANY    ANY    ANY  /_profiler/search
  _profiler_search_bar      ANY    ANY    ANY  /_profiler/search_bar
  _profiler_purge           ANY    ANY    ANY  /_profiler/purge
  _profiler_info            ANY    ANY    ANY  /_profiler/info/{about}
  _profiler_phpinfo         ANY    ANY    ANY  /_profiler/phpinfo
  _profiler_search_results  ANY    ANY    ANY  /_profiler/{token}/search/results
  _profiler                 ANY    ANY    ANY  /_profiler/{token}
  _profiler_router          ANY    ANY    ANY  /_profiler/{token}/router
  _profiler_exception       ANY    ANY    ANY  /_profiler/{token}/exception
  _profiler_exception_css   ANY    ANY    ANY  /_profiler/{token}/exception.css
  _configurator_home        ANY    ANY    ANY  /_configurator/
  _configurator_step        ANY    ANY    ANY  /_configurator/step/{index}
  _configurator_final       ANY    ANY    ANY  /_configurator/final
  _twig_error_test          ANY    ANY    ANY  /_error/{code}.{_format}
  homepage                  ANY    ANY    ANY  /app/example
  _welcome                  ANY    ANY    ANY  /
  _demo_login               ANY    ANY    ANY  /demo/secured/login
  _demo_security_check      ANY    ANY    ANY  /demo/secured/login_check
  _demo_logout              ANY    ANY    ANY  /demo/secured/logout
  acme_demo_secured_hello   ANY    ANY    ANY  /demo/secured/hello
  _demo_secured_hello       ANY    ANY    ANY  /demo/secured/hello/{name}
  _demo_secured_hello_admin ANY    ANY    ANY  /demo/secured/hello/admin/{name}
  _demo                     ANY    ANY    ANY  /demo/
  _demo_hello               ANY    ANY    ANY  /demo/hello/{name}
  _demo_contact             ANY    ANY    ANY  /demo/contact

UPDATE:

weird I dealt with the errors shown on the pages. I got rid of the line :    : throw 0 < count($allow) ? new MethodNotAllowedException(array_unique($allow)) : new ResourceNotFoundException(); [1/2] ResourceNotFoundException:

and it seems to work

but when I deleted line 2117 in classes.php (the elseif so 3 lines) in /opt/lampp/htdocs/Symfony/app/cache/dev/classes.php I get a new error even when I put the elseif back ...

---

Here's the message:

hoops, looks like something went wrong.
1/1 FatalErrorException in classes.php line 2117: Parse Error: syntax error, unexpected 'elseif' (T_ELSEIF)

```
in classes.php line 2117
```

---

Since I started installation only in var/www and not opt/ I'm clueless, any help welcome!

Comment: How do you register these routes? Any code?

Comment: which file do I need to go to give you the code? I did everything by default the "hello" is a default controller installed in symfony2

Answer (score 0):

1. Check you app/config/routes (dev and base)
2. At main folder run command `app/console cache:clear` test if its working
3. At main folder run command `app/console route:debug` view if there is listed your route

Comment: weird I dealt with the errors shown on the pages. I got rid of the line : [1/2] ResourceNotFoundException: -

Comment: cd to /www/Symfony and inside it try : php app/console cache:clear      !!! All app/cache files are temporary so you must not fix them as they will be removed at some point